# How to change selected background color of my image?

Tags: android

I want to change the selected background color of my image on touch event.
Should i need to draw that image on canvas or it can be done by imageview only?
Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried 
`viewid.setBackgroundResource (somecolor)`
to set the color?
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource(int)

To set the background color on a canvas, do something like this:
The first FF is the alpha value

`Paint p=new Paint();
p.setColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
canvas.drawPaint(paint);`